# How to execute composite sql queries in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I execute the following query and retrieve a result via prepared statement:

```
INSERT INTO vcVisitors (sid) VALUES (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Is there a way to execute both two statements at once?

I've tried to do the following:

```
Connection con = DbManager.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = con.PrepareStatement(
     "INSERT INTO vcVisitors (sid) VALUES (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
ps.setInt(1, 10);
ResultSet rs = ps.exequteQuery();
rs.next();
return rs.getInt("LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

but it gives me an error that executeQuery can't execute such a query,
I've also tried to replace executeQuery by the following:

```
ps.execute();
rs = ps.getResultSet();
```

but it gives me SQL syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1
```

but there are no problems with executing query 
**"INSERT INTO vcVisitors (sid) VALUES ('10'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"** directly from mysql console.

Comment: I don't think thats possible. Especially not with an `INSERT` and an `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While updating (inserting) data use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`. Try executing `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` as another query.

But it is not portable query. I suggest using `Statement.getGeneratedKeys` instead. Please look here: [JDBC (MySQL) Retrieving AUTO_INCREMENT Column Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id).

Here is an example of properly used LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
    Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   try {

    //
    // Create a Statement instance that we can use for
    // 'normal' result sets.

    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    //
    // Issue the DDL queries for the table for this example
    //

    stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS autoIncTutorial");
    stmt.executeUpdate(
            "CREATE TABLE autoIncTutorial ("
            + "priKey INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
            + "dataField VARCHAR(64), PRIMARY KEY (priKey))");

    //
    // Insert one row that will generate an AUTO INCREMENT
    // key in the 'priKey' field
    //

    stmt.executeUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO autoIncTutorial (dataField) "
            + "values ('Can I Get the Auto Increment Field?')");

    //
    // Use the MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID()
    // function to do the same thing as getGeneratedKeys()
    //

    int autoIncKeyFromFunc = -1;
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");

    if (rs.next()) {
        autoIncKeyFromFunc = rs.getInt(1);
    } else {
        // throw an exception from here
    }

    rs.close();

    System.out.println("Key returned from " +
                       "'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()': " +
                       autoIncKeyFromFunc);

} finally {

    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

and here the same with getGeneratedKeys:

```
     Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   try {

    //
    // Create a Statement instance that we can use for
    // 'normal' result sets assuming you have a
    // Connection 'conn' to a MySQL database already
    // available

    stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                                java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    //
    // Issue the DDL queries for the table for this example
    //

    stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS autoIncTutorial");
    stmt.executeUpdate(
            "CREATE TABLE autoIncTutorial ("
            + "priKey INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
            + "dataField VARCHAR(64), PRIMARY KEY (priKey))");

    //
    // Insert one row that will generate an AUTO INCREMENT
    // key in the 'priKey' field
    //

    stmt.executeUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO autoIncTutorial (dataField) "
            + "values ('Can I Get the Auto Increment Field?')",
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    //
    // Example of using Statement.getGeneratedKeys()
    // to retrieve the value of an auto-increment
    // value
    //

    int autoIncKeyFromApi = -1;

    rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

    if (rs.next()) {
        autoIncKeyFromApi = rs.getInt(1);
    } else {

        // throw an exception from here
    }

    rs.close();

    rs = null;

    System.out.println("Key returned from getGeneratedKeys():"
        + autoIncKeyFromApi);
} finally {

    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He specifically wants to execute both queries at once.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, this won't work. But it looks like you just want to get the ID of the last insert. To achieve that, you can use the [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) method of the [`Statement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
Connection con = DbManager.getConnection();
int lastid = 0;

PreparedStatement psInsert = con.PrepareStatement(
     "INSERT INTO vcVisitors (sid) VALUES (?)");
psInsert.setInt(1, 10);
psInsert.executeUpdate();

PreparedStatement psSelect = 
    con.PrepareStatement("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lastid");
ResultSet rs = psSelect.executeQuery();
rs.next();

lastid = rs.getInt("lastid");

rs.close();
psInsert.close();
psSelect.close();
con.close();
return lastid;
```

Comment: Yes, is surely works, but my question is how to execute several queries at once

Comment: @tsds: But two queries are always run as two queries.