# Multiple queries executed in java in single statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to execute something like this using JDBC as it currently provides an exception even though it is possible in the MySQL query browser.

```
"SELECT FROM * TABLE;INSERT INTO TABLE;"
```

While I do realize that it is possible with having the SQL query string being split and the statement executed twice but I was wondering if there is a one time approach for this.

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "databaseinjection";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String sqlUsername = "root"; 
    String sqlPassword = "abc";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, sqlUsername, sqlPassword);
```

Comment: put into a stored procedure, call the stored procedure. means you also dont have to redeploy your code when you want to make a change.

Comment: There is a property you have to set in connection string `allowMultiQueries=true`.

Comment: probable duplicate : How to execute composite sql queries in java?[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773393/how-to-execute-composite-sql-queries-in-java

Comment: Hi Rahul, for this project I am using a plain old connection object and do you know where I should set "allowMultiQueries=true". Have added the connection object code in the question

Comment: When I used "allowMultiQueries=true", it gave me DisconnectNonTransientException. Why?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

*I was wondering if it is possible to execute something like this using JDBC.*

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE;INSERT INTO TABLE;"
```

Yes it is possible. There are two ways, as far as I know. They are

1. By setting database connection property to allow multiple queries,
   separated by a semi-colon by default.
2. By calling a stored procedure that returns cursors implicit.

Following examples demonstrate the above two possibilities.

**Example 1**: ( To allow multiple queries ):

While sending a connection request, you need to append a connection property `allowMultiQueries=true` to the database url. This is additional connection property to those if already exists some, like `autoReConnect=true`, etc.. Acceptable values for `allowMultiQueries` property are `true`, `false`, `yes`, and `no`. Any other value is rejected at runtime with an `SQLException`.

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

Unless such instruction is passed, an `SQLException` is thrown.

You have to use [`execute( String sql )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) or its other variants to fetch results of the query execution.

```
boolean hasMoreResultSets = stmt.execute( multiQuerySqlString );
```

To iterate through and process results you require following steps:

```
READING_QUERY_RESULTS: // label  
    while ( hasMoreResultSets || stmt.getUpdateCount() != -1 ) {  
        if ( hasMoreResultSets ) {  
            Resultset rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            // handle your rs here
        } // if has rs
        else { // if ddl/dml/...
            int queryResult = stmt.getUpdateCount();  
            if ( queryResult == -1 ) { // no more queries processed  
                break READING_QUERY_RESULTS;  
            } // no more queries processed  
            // handle success, failure, generated keys, etc here
        } // if ddl/dml/...

        // check to continue in the loop  
        hasMoreResultSets = stmt.getMoreResults();  
    } // while results
```

**Example 2**: Steps to follow:

1. Create a procedure with one or more `select`, and `DML` queries.
2. Call it from java using `CallableStatement`.
3. You can capture multiple `ResultSet`s executed in procedure.
   DML results can't be captured but can issue another `select`
   to find how the rows are affected in the table.

*Sample table and procedure*:

```
mysql> create table tbl_mq( i int not null auto_increment, name varchar(10), primary key (i) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure multi_query()
    -> begin
    ->  select count(*) as name_count from tbl_mq;
    ->  insert into tbl_mq( names ) values ( 'ravi' );
    ->  select last_insert_id();
    ->  select * from tbl_mq;
    -> end;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call multi_query();
+------------+
| name_count |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                3 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---+------+
| i | name |
+---+------+
| 1 | ravi |
+---+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

*Call Procedure from Java*:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall( "call multi_query()" );  
boolean hasMoreResultSets = cstmt.execute();  
READING_QUERY_RESULTS:  
    while ( hasMoreResultSets ) {  
        Resultset rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        // handle your rs here
    } // while has more rs
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with the embedded version of Derby.

Comment: @user2428118: Reason? Any errors observed? Did you check if Driver supports this feature?

Comment: i have added allowMultiQueries=true and works fine :)

Answer (score 39):

You can use Batch update but queries must be action(i.e. insert,update and delete) queries

```
Statement s = c.createStatement();
String s1 = "update emp set name='abc' where salary=984";
String s2 = "insert into emp values ('Osama',1420)";  
s.addBatch(s1);
s.addBatch(s2);     
s.executeBatch();
```

Comment: You can't use this approach for "call sprocname('abc',984)" queries?

Answer (score 22):

Hint: If you have more than one connection property then separate them with:

```
&amp;
```

To give you somthing like:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/glyndwr?autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true"
```

I hope this helps some one.

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 12):

Based on my testing, the correct flag is "allowMultiQueries=true"

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you try and write a `Stored Procedure` for this?

You can get the `Result Set` out and in the same `Stored Procedure` you can `Insert` what you want.

The only thing is you might not get the newly inserted rows in the `Result Set` if you `Insert` after the `Select`.

Comment: You don't always have the permission to write a Stored Procedure. E.g. it's a client's database that you're only allowed to select from.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way for multy selection/update/insert/delete. You can run as many update/insert/delete as u want after select (you have to make a select first(a dummy if needed)) with executeUpdate(str) (just use new int(count1,count2,...)) and if u need a new selection close 'statement' and 'connection' and make new for next select. Like example:

```
String str1 = "select * from users";
String str9 = "INSERT INTO `port`(device_id, potition, port_type, di_p_pt) VALUE ('"+value1+"', '"+value2+"', '"+value3+"', '"+value4+"')";
String str2 = "Select port_id from port where device_id = '"+value1+"' and potition = '"+value2+"' and port_type = '"+value3+"' ";
try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    theConnection=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbuser,dbpassword);  
    theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement(str1);
    ResultSet theResult = theStatement.executeQuery();
    int count8 = theStatement.executeUpdate(str9);
    theStatement.close();
    theConnection.close();
    theConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbuser,dbpassword);
    theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement(str2);
    theResult = theStatement.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<Port> portList = new ArrayList<Port>();
    while (theResult.next()) {
        Port port = new Port();
        port.setPort_id(theResult.getInt("port_id"));

        portList.add(port);
    }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Opening a DB  connection is very costlier. Not a good practice doing that everytime. The which you have given should makes n number DB hits for n number of queries which leads to poor performance.

Comment: Seems incorrect. [`Statement#executeUpdate( String sql )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement`, as explicitly stated in the Javadoc. So, your line `int count8 = theStatement.executeUpdate(str9);` seems impossible.