# How to execute multiple SQL statements from java

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to execute the multiple queries or job in one execute.
Something like this
eg:

```java
String query = """
        SELECT * FROM tab1;
        INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES( … );
        UPDATE tab1 … ;
        DELETE FROM tab1 … ;
        """ ; 
Statement st = con1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Or multiple SELECT queries. Queries will be dynamic.

But I am not able to do this. What is the way to run multiple queries separated by semicolon?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to handle multiple SELECT result sets, or handling batch updating of multiple INSERTS. You are getting 3 very different answers which would indicate a question is not specific enough.

Comment: Please have a look over this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you can achieve that using following example uses addBatch & executeBatch commands to execute multiple SQL commands simultaneously.

Batch processing allows you to group related SQL statements into a batch and submit them with one call to the database. [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm)

When you send several SQL statements to the database at once, you reduce the amount of communication overhead, thereby improving performance.

- JDBC drivers are not required to support this feature. You should use the `DatabaseMetaData.supportsBatchUpdates()` method to determine if the target database supports batch update processing. The method returns true if your JDBC driver supports this feature.
- The **[addBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch())()** method of Statement, PreparedStatement, and CallableStatement is used to add individual statements to the batch. The `executeBatch()` is used to start the execution of all the statements grouped together.
- The **[executeBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())()** returns an array of integers, and each element of the array represents the update count for the respective update statement.
- Just as you can add statements to a batch for processing, you can remove them with the **[clearBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#clearBatch())()** method. This method removes all the statements you added with the `addBatch()` method. However, you cannot selectively choose which statement to remove.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcConn {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
      ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDb","name","pass");

      Statement stmt = con.createStatement
      (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
      ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      String insertEmp1 = "insert into emp values
      (10,'jay','trainee')";
      String insertEmp2 = "insert into emp values
      (11,'jayes','trainee')";
      String insertEmp3 = "insert into emp values
      (12,'shail','trainee')";
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      stmt.addBatch(insertEmp1);//inserting Query in stmt
      stmt.addBatch(insertEmp2);
      stmt.addBatch(insertEmp3);
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
      rs.last();
      System.out.println("rows before batch execution= "
      + rs.getRow());
      stmt.executeBatch();
      con.commit();
      System.out.println("Batch executed");
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
      rs.last();
      System.out.println("rows after batch execution= "
      + rs.getRow());
   }
}
```

refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_executebatch.htm

Comment: I'm not sure you're answering the question. You're talking about INSERT statements being batched, and the question is related to multiple SELECT statements and therefore must handle ResultSets

Comment: @Brad the question is `I want to execute the multiple queries or job in one execute` so i thing for multiple queries..

Comment: Maybe a working example, but a bit unformatted. I found this one more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Comment: Perfect explaination - worked a treat, I am using Derby DB too :)

Comment: @thonnor glad it helped.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure that you want to send two SELECT statements in one request statement because you may not be able to access both `ResultSet`s. The database may only return the last result set.

**Multiple ResultSets**

However, if you're calling a stored procedure that you know can return multiple resultsets something like this will work

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(...);
try {
...

boolean results = stmt.execute();

while (results) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        // read the data
    }
    } finally {
        try { rs.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
    }

    // are there anymore result sets?
    results = stmt.getMoreResults();
}
} finally {
    try { stmt.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
}
```

**Multiple SQL Statements**

If you're talking about multiple SQL statements and only one SELECT then your database should be able to support the one `String` of SQL. For example I have used something like this on Sybase

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer( "SET rowcount 100" );
sql.append( " SELECT * FROM tbl_books ..." );
sql.append( " SET rowcount 0" );

stmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql.toString() );
```

This will depend on the syntax supported by your database. In this example note the addtional `spaces` padding the statements so that there is white space between the staments.

Comment: The original question refers to non-homogeneous statements - so this answer is more correct then the one referring to a batch execution.

Comment: Should I use StringBuffer or simple concat will suffice in this case ?

Comment: You can use `concat` too because it doesn't matter how you actually construct the `String`.