# SQLite syntax error but only on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, sqlite, samsung-mobile

I have a strange problem which seems to be device specific: My Android podcast player app fetches data from a server and inserts it into a database. For more than 100 users everything is working fine. But for one user the data insertion fails with an SQLite syntax error, but just on his Galaxy Tab (GT-P7310) with Android 4.0.4. The same user also has two phones (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 5) where the same data works without problems.

Furth on I can execute the statement without problems in a local SQLite installation.

This is the statement that causes the problem with a few line breaks added to make it more readable:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO podcast
(uid, uri, url, title, subTitle, link, authorName, authorEmail, categories, keywords, description, imageUrl, modified, subscribed, settings_autoAddEpisodes, settings_autoDownload, settings_maxKeptEpisodes, settings_playbackSpeed, id)
VALUES
(19, 'http://api.sr.se/api/rss/pod/17155', 'http://api.sr.se/api/rss/pod/17155', 'Luuk & Lokko', NULL, 'http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4296', 'Luuk & Lokko', 'podd@sverigesradio.se', '[{"name":"Society \u0026 Culture"}]', '[]', 'Luuk &amp; Lokko Ã¤r ett schemalagt veckosamtal dÃ¤r Kristian Luuk och Andres Lokko pratar med varandra om Ã¤mnen som de har bestÃ¤mt pÃ¥ fÃ¶rhand. Vissa infall kan fÃ¶rekomma men de kommer att vara ytterst tyglade samt relativt fÃ¥.', 'http://sverigesradio.se/diverse/appdata/isidor/images/news_images/4296/2143980_512_512.jpg', 1386174193000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(580, 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18535', 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18535', 'FotbollsArena Radiosporten', NULL, 'http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4410', 'FotbollsArena Radiosporten', 'podd@sverigesradio.se', '[{"name":"Sports \u0026 Recreation"}]', '[]', 'Varje vecka diskuterar Radiosportens Richard Henriksson med gÃ¤ster det senaste och hetaste i fotbollsvÃ¤rlden. Allt frÃ¥n allsvenskan och landslaget till de stora ligorna i Europa.', 'http://sverigesradio.se/diverse/appdata/isidor/images/news_images/4410/2708666_512_512.jpg', 1386173280000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(581, 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18656', 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18656', 'Musikguiden i P3 ', NULL, 'http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4067', 'Musikguiden i P3', 'podd@sverigesradio.se', '[{"name":"Music"}]', '[]', ': Jenny Seth presenterar Musikguiden i P3s journalistiska magasin. Vi gÃ¥r pÃ¥ djupet i musik frÃ¥n alla genres genom intervjuer, reportage och gÃ¤ster i studion.', 'http://sverigesradio.se/diverse/appdata/isidor/images/news_images/4067/2472633_512_512.jpg', 1386173083000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(796, 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/jukebox/podcast.xml', 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/jukebox/podcast.xml', 'Stones Throw Podcast', NULL, 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/podcast', 'Stones Throw Records', 'losangeles@stonesthrow.com', '[{"name":"Music"}]', '[]', 'Music from Stones Throw and the Stones Throw DJs. Archive available at stonesthrow.com', 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/images/stonesthrowpodcast.jpg', 1381769169000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(1174, 'http://swedroid.libsyn.com/rss', 'http://swedroid.libsyn.com/rss', 'Swedroid Podcast', '', 'http://www.swedroid.se', 'Swedroid', 'podcast@swedroid.se', '[{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Gadgets"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Podcasting"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Tech News"}]', '["android","podcast","smartphone","swedroid"]', 'Intresserad av Android, Google och smarta telefoner? Missa inte Swedroids podcast! Vi gÃ¥r varje vecka igenom det senaste pÃ¥ Androidfronten.', 'http://assets.libsyn.com/content/6515469.jpg', 1386609291000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(247, 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/filipochfredrik/podcast', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/filipochfredrik/podcast', 'Filip och Fredriks podcast', 'Filip & Fredrik och en mikrofon, en gÃ¥ng i veckan. UtnÃ¤mnd till Sveriges bÃ¤sta podcast 2011 (Svenska podradiopriset).', 'http://www.filipochfredrik.com', 'Filip och Fredrik', 'podcast@filipochfredrik.com', '[{"name":"Comedy"}]', '[]', 'Filip & Fredrik och en mikrofon, en gÃ¥ng i veckan. UtnÃ¤mnd till Sveriges bÃ¤sta podcast 2011 (Svenska podradiopriset).', 'http://www.filipochfredrik.com/wp-content/themes/filipochfredrik/images/ff-podcast-600x600.jpg', 1382878323000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, 'http://alexosigge.libsyn.com/rss', 'http://alexosigge.libsyn.com/rss', 'Alex & Sigges podcast', '', 'http://alexosigge.libsyn.com', 'Alex Schulman &amp; Sigge Eklund', 'alexochsigge@gmail.com', '[{"name":"Comedy"}]', '["schulmans","podcast","eklund","sigge","sigges","schulman","eklunds","alex","radio","podradio"]', 'Alex Schulmans och Sigge Eklunds podcast som publiceras en gÃ¥ng i veckan.', 'http://assets.libsyn.com/content/4601369.jpg', 1386022416000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(73, 'http://computersweden.libsyn.com/rss', 'http://computersweden.libsyn.com/rss', 'Computer Swedens podcast', 'CS ger dig koll pÃ¥ veckans viktigaste it-hÃ¤ndelser', 'http://computersweden.libsyn.com', 'Bjorn Olsberg', 'bjorn.olsberg@idg.se', '[{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Podcasting"},{"name":"News \u0026 Politics"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Tech News"}]', '["computer","cs","sweden"]', 'Lyssna i stÃ¤llet fÃ¶r att lÃ¤sa! I Computer Swedens podcast sammanfattar vi it-nyheterna den senaste veckan, med fokus pÃ¥ de tre Ã¤mnen som vi tycker Ã¤r intressantast att diskutera. Nyhetschef Sverker Brundin, debattredaktÃ¶r Eva Melin och teknikreporter Tomas Zirn blandar hÃ¥rt med mjukt och hÃ¶gt med lÃ¥gt varje torsdag kl 17.00.', 'http://assets.libsyn.com/content/6406700.jpg', 1386023131000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(212, 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ThisIsMyNextPodcast', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ThisIsMyNextPodcast', 'The Vergecast', 'The Vergecast', 'http://www.theverge.com/verge/verge_archives/show?mode=EntryGroup&slug=the-vergecast', 'Joshua Topolsky, Nilay Patel, Paul Miller', 'joshua@theverge.com', '[{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Tech News"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Gadgets"},{"name":"Technology"}]', '["joshua","gadgets","pcs","this","mac","smartphones","technology","miller","next","apple","pc","gadget","google","laptops","macs","is","paul","tech","ipad","patel","news","nilay","iphone","windows","android","timp","osx","podcast","my","topolsky","microsoft","tablet","tabelts"]', 'The Vergecast is your source for an irreverent and informative look at what''s happening right now (and next) in the world of technology and gadgets. Hosted by Joshua Topolsky, Nilay Patel, and Paul Miller alongside a cavalcade of tech luminaries, The Vergecast is the only podcast you need to make sense of the week in tech news. And your life.', 'http://assets.sbnation.com/assets/770431/vergecast.png', 1382873693000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(173, 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Iterate', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Iterate', 'Iterate', 'Iterate: Loop until done.', 'http://www.iterate.tv/', 'Edwards, Clifford, Ritchie', 'rene@mobilenations.com', '[{"name":"Arts","subCategory":"Design"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Software How-To"}]', '["icons","windows","interface","design","ipad","x","ux","blackberry","ui","webos","user","phone","iphone","mac","android","experience","os"]', 'Iterate brings together the best designers and app producers in the business to talk user interface and user experience from concept to implementation. Hosted by Marc Edwards, Seth Clifford, and Rene Ritchie. Loop until done.', 'http://www.mobilenations.com/broadcasting/podcast_iterate_1400.jpg', 1382885371000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

And here the original statement on a single line

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO podcast (uid, uri, url, title, subTitle, link, authorName, authorEmail, categories, keywords, description, imageUrl, modified, subscribed, settings_autoAddEpisodes, settings_autoDownload, settings_maxKeptEpisodes, settings_playbackSpeed, id) VALUES (19, 'http://api.sr.se/api/rss/pod/17155', 'http://api.sr.se/api/rss/pod/17155', 'Luuk & Lokko', NULL, 'http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4296', 'Luuk & Lokko', 'podd@sverigesradio.se', '[{"name":"Society \u0026 Culture"}]', '[]', 'Luuk &amp; Lokko Ã¤r ett schemalagt veckosamtal dÃ¤r Kristian Luuk och Andres Lokko pratar med varandra om Ã¤mnen som de har bestÃ¤mt pÃ¥ fÃ¶rhand. Vissa infall kan fÃ¶rekomma men de kommer att vara ytterst tyglade samt relativt fÃ¥.', 'http://sverigesradio.se/diverse/appdata/isidor/images/news_images/4296/2143980_512_512.jpg', 1386174193000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (580, 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18535', 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18535', 'FotbollsArena Radiosporten', NULL, 'http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4410', 'FotbollsArena Radiosporten', 'podd@sverigesradio.se', '[{"name":"Sports \u0026 Recreation"}]', '[]', 'Varje vecka diskuterar Radiosportens Richard Henriksson med gÃ¤ster det senaste och hetaste i fotbollsvÃ¤rlden. Allt frÃ¥n allsvenskan och landslaget till de stora ligorna i Europa.', 'http://sverigesradio.se/diverse/appdata/isidor/images/news_images/4410/2708666_512_512.jpg', 1386173280000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (581, 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18656', 'http://sverigesradio.se/api/rss/pod/18656', 'Musikguiden i P3 ', NULL, 'http://sverigesradio.se/sida/default.aspx?programid=4067', 'Musikguiden i P3', 'podd@sverigesradio.se', '[{"name":"Music"}]', '[]', ': Jenny Seth presenterar Musikguiden i P3s journalistiska magasin. Vi gÃ¥r pÃ¥ djupet i musik frÃ¥n alla genres genom intervjuer, reportage och gÃ¤ster i studion.', 'http://sverigesradio.se/diverse/appdata/isidor/images/news_images/4067/2472633_512_512.jpg', 1386173083000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (796, 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/jukebox/podcast.xml', 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/jukebox/podcast.xml', 'Stones Throw Podcast', NULL, 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/podcast', 'Stones Throw Records', 'losangeles@stonesthrow.com', '[{"name":"Music"}]', '[]', 'Music from Stones Throw and the Stones Throw DJs. Archive available at stonesthrow.com', 'http://www.stonesthrow.com/images/stonesthrowpodcast.jpg', 1381769169000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (1174, 'http://swedroid.libsyn.com/rss', 'http://swedroid.libsyn.com/rss', 'Swedroid Podcast', '', 'http://www.swedroid.se', 'Swedroid', 'podcast@swedroid.se', '[{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Gadgets"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Podcasting"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Tech News"}]', '["android","podcast","smartphone","swedroid"]', 'Intresserad av Android, Google och smarta telefoner? Missa inte Swedroids podcast! Vi gÃ¥r varje vecka igenom det senaste pÃ¥ Androidfronten.', 'http://assets.libsyn.com/content/6515469.jpg', 1386609291000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (247, 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/filipochfredrik/podcast', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/filipochfredrik/podcast', 'Filip och Fredriks podcast', 'Filip & Fredrik och en mikrofon, en gÃ¥ng i veckan. UtnÃ¤mnd till Sveriges bÃ¤sta podcast 2011 (Svenska podradiopriset).', 'http://www.filipochfredrik.com', 'Filip och Fredrik', 'podcast@filipochfredrik.com', '[{"name":"Comedy"}]', '[]', 'Filip & Fredrik och en mikrofon, en gÃ¥ng i veckan. UtnÃ¤mnd till Sveriges bÃ¤sta podcast 2011 (Svenska podradiopriset).', 'http://www.filipochfredrik.com/wp-content/themes/filipochfredrik/images/ff-podcast-600x600.jpg', 1382878323000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (6, 'http://alexosigge.libsyn.com/rss', 'http://alexosigge.libsyn.com/rss', 'Alex & Sigges podcast', '', 'http://alexosigge.libsyn.com', 'Alex Schulman &amp; Sigge Eklund', 'alexochsigge@gmail.com', '[{"name":"Comedy"}]', '["schulmans","podcast","eklund","sigge","sigges","schulman","eklunds","alex","radio","podradio"]', 'Alex Schulmans och Sigge Eklunds podcast som publiceras en gÃ¥ng i veckan.', 'http://assets.libsyn.com/content/4601369.jpg', 1386022416000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (73, 'http://computersweden.libsyn.com/rss', 'http://computersweden.libsyn.com/rss', 'Computer Swedens podcast', 'CS ger dig koll pÃ¥ veckans viktigaste it-hÃ¤ndelser', 'http://computersweden.libsyn.com', 'Bjorn Olsberg', 'bjorn.olsberg@idg.se', '[{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Podcasting"},{"name":"News \u0026 Politics"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Tech News"}]', '["computer","cs","sweden"]', 'Lyssna i stÃ¤llet fÃ¶r att lÃ¤sa! I Computer Swedens podcast sammanfattar vi it-nyheterna den senaste veckan, med fokus pÃ¥ de tre Ã¤mnen som vi tycker Ã¤r intressantast att diskutera. Nyhetschef Sverker Brundin, debattredaktÃ¶r Eva Melin och teknikreporter Tomas Zirn blandar hÃ¥rt med mjukt och hÃ¶gt med lÃ¥gt varje torsdag kl 17.00.', 'http://assets.libsyn.com/content/6406700.jpg', 1386023131000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (212, 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ThisIsMyNextPodcast', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ThisIsMyNextPodcast', 'The Vergecast', 'The Vergecast', 'http://www.theverge.com/verge/verge_archives/show?mode=EntryGroup&slug=the-vergecast', 'Joshua Topolsky, Nilay Patel, Paul Miller', 'joshua@theverge.com', '[{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Tech News"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Gadgets"},{"name":"Technology"}]', '["joshua","gadgets","pcs","this","mac","smartphones","technology","miller","next","apple","pc","gadget","google","laptops","macs","is","paul","tech","ipad","patel","news","nilay","iphone","windows","android","timp","osx","podcast","my","topolsky","microsoft","tablet","tabelts"]', 'The Vergecast is your source for an irreverent and informative look at what''s happening right now (and next) in the world of technology and gadgets. Hosted by Joshua Topolsky, Nilay Patel, and Paul Miller alongside a cavalcade of tech luminaries, The Vergecast is the only podcast you need to make sense of the week in tech news. And your life.', 'http://assets.sbnation.com/assets/770431/vergecast.png', 1382873693000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL), (173, 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Iterate', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Iterate', 'Iterate', 'Iterate: Loop until done.', 'http://www.iterate.tv/', 'Edwards, Clifford, Ritchie', 'rene@mobilenations.com', '[{"name":"Arts","subCategory":"Design"},{"name":"Technology","subCategory":"Software How-To"}]', '["icons","windows","interface","design","ipad","x","ux","blackberry","ui","webos","user","phone","iphone","mac","android","experience","os"]', 'Iterate brings together the best designers and app producers in the business to talk user interface and user experience from concept to implementation. Hosted by Marc Edwards, Seth Clifford, and Rene Ritchie. Loop until done.', 'http://www.mobilenations.com/broadcasting/podcast_iterate_1400.jpg', 1382885371000, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

The statement causes this stack trace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling: 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:84) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2019) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1959) ~[na:0.0]
```

Here some more detailed device information:

```
DEVICE
======
display name: IMM76D.XXLPV
manufacturer: samsung
model:        GT-P7310
product:      GT-P7310
brand:        samsung
tags:         release-keys
```

And the Android details:

```
ANDROID
=======
release:  4.0.4
codename: REL
sdk:      15
locale:   sv_SE
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this in one massive statement rather than individual ones wrapped in a transaction? Also, is there a reason you are not using positional parameters (`?`)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I already wrap dozens of the shown statement into a transaction. My assumption was that a multi insert is still faster than multiple single inserts -- even if using prepared statements. But I agree that prepared statements with positional parameters would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax support for inserting multiple rows with a single SQL statement was only [added in sqlite 3.7.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database/1609688#1609688). Some manufacturers have older versions of sqlite in their devices. Isn't platform fragmentation fun, eh.

You can fix it by breaking up the inserts to inserting one row at a time.

While there, also consider changing to `?` literal placeholders and using `bindArgs` with [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to supply the values. Or just use `ContentValues` with `insert()`.

For performance, wrap multiple inserts (say, max 1000) in a single database transaction.

Comment: That's it. I've experienced a lot about Android fragmentation during the last year, but haven't thought that a SQL-feature I'm used to since ten years isn't supported on Android 4 :-/ BTW: I'm already using transactions because I inserted hundred of items broken down into 10-item-batches. And you're right regarding prepared statements, but building the statements was easier in this context and as the data comes from my own server security isn't a topic.

Comment: "Some manufacturers have older versions of sqlite in their devices" -- note that the feature in question was only added to SQLite itself in March 2012 (http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html). "but haven't thought that a SQL-feature I'm used to since ten years isn't supported on Android 4" -- Android 4.0.4 was released nine days after SQLite added this feature, and so that's not really a reasonable expectation. It is reasonable to expect it on Android 4.1+ (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/115145), but as laalto noted, manufacturers can downgrade their SQLite, though they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not try inserting half the rows first, then second half and keep halving until you pinpoint the row/rows which are causing the issue. Should make it much easier to spot the issue.

Comment: It's a user's device -- so this is a little bit difficult. But I will think about building a special version for him.

Comment: IMHO as your answer isn't a solution to the problem (it's only a hint for further investigation) a comment to my original question would have been a more appropriate choice.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to use parameter for inserting values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413306/run-many-sqllite-sentences-in-java/20421100?noredirect=1#20421100) is a good way to do this

Answer (score 0):

To build on laalto's answer,

Use `db.beginTransaction();` then loop and insert your rows with `initialValues = new ContentValues();` and  `initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);` ect.. then at the end write `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` and `db.endTransaction();`

I use it to insert 9k rows in under 5 seconds.

Comment: I am already using transaction to bundle dozens of the shown statement. This isn't really the issue here and doesn't solve the problem. IMHO this info as a comment on laalto's answer would have been a better choice.