# How to run .sql file using java without manually parsing the document

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

How to run .sql file using java without manually parsing the document. Is there any prewritten class to do the parsing if it has to be done?

Comment: [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but this may help you.

In MySQL JDBC implementation: [setLocalInfileInputStream()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) sets an InputStream instance that will be used to send data to the MySQL server for a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement rather than a FileInputStream or URLInputStream that represents the path given as an argument to the statement.