# How to run several select queries with same statement and result set?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to write simple Java web application to get data from a database.
I need to run several select queries on different database tables.

```
String queryOne = "select firstname from employees where empid = id";
String queryOne = "select title from books where bookid = bid";
String queryOne = "select auther from books where bookid = bid";
```

And I tried to do it like this:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = statement.executeQuery(queryOne);

while (rs1.nest()) {
String firstName = rs1.getString(1);
}
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

I can only run one query with the same statement. How can I execute several queries with the same statement?

Comment: May this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Comment: I get datasource like this: DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/DatabaseName"); How do I add allowMultipleQueries flag to that string? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you care? Why would using several statements be a bad thing?

Comment: Use a `connection.prepareStatement()` and the `PreparedStatement` you get is "reusable". You should do this always to get parameter substitution too.

Comment: If I use PreparedStatement how do I get several resultsets?

Comment: @SeanKilb Oh, I misread your question. You can only get multiple resultsets with JDBC when calling a stored procedure. If you want to minimise DB roundtrips, you'll have to make a single `UNION` query and add a discriminator column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could perhaps store the queries you want in an array and iterate through it like:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
try {
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  try {
    for (String q : queries) {  //queries is an array containing the 3 queries
      ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery(q);
      try {
        rset.getString(1);
      } finally {
        rset.close();
      }
    }
  } finally {
    stmt.close();
  }
} finally {
  conn.close();
}
```

P.S. It is a good idea to enclose your Connection, ResultSet and Statement objects in a try...finally block in order for you to ensure that you are able to close() them **everytime**.

Comment: As of Java 7, you can use *try-with-resources*

Comment: @ EmanuelSaringan don't you think there will be any performance overhead with this approach?

Comment: Any reply how to overcome performance overhead ? . I have similar requirement but performance is main concern

Answer (score 2):

why can't you join tables and do 1 query to get all results? Your queries seems to be very unoptimised. As an example:

> select title from books where bookid = bid
>   select auther from books where bookid = bid

can be done easily in one query:

> select title, author from books where bookid = bid