# “ORA-00922: missing or invalid option” when trying to insert into table

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

When i run SQL query in oracle sql developer it is work, but in jdbc this query doesn't work and catch the java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option. Could anyone help me ? There is my query below

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TABLE (
    ID VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) PRIMARY KEY, 
    NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE));
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (
    ID, NAME)
VALUES ('My_Id' , 'My_Name' );
```

Comment: Try running these as two separate statements rather than as one statement.

Comment: Show the Java code you use to execute this. Note that you can only execute **one** statement at a time.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515471/can-i-execute-mysql-queries-separated-by-semicolon-in-jdbc-5 can you please check? The key issue is that you are trying to exec 2 statements in one go.

Comment: From the comment on an answer you are running something slightly different via JDBC, not what you've shown. Without the semicolons the `INSERT` keyword will be seen as part of the `CREATE`, and it is indeed invalid as part of that command. You cannot run two statements as one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is just a quick guess, because I have no oracle available to proof it, but with MyBatis (which is based on JDBC) I had this behavior with the last `;`. Please try to remove it in your JDBC query.

Please create the temporary table in a first statement, then in a second statement add your data.

Comment: I remove `;` characters in jdbc query.
If i doesn't remove this charcters jdbc catch the `Invalid charcters exception`.