# JDBC Oracle Alter session missing or invalid option

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to alter the schema for the newly created JDBC connection with the following code:

```
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=abcd;";
            stmt.execute(sql);
```

This code throws `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

If I try to run the `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="abcd";` command through Oracle SQL Developer it successfully alters the schema.

How can I alter the schema through Java?

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the semicolon at the end. `"ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=abcd"` 
[“ORA-00922: missing or invalid option” when trying to insert into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818416/ora-00922-missing-or-invalid-option-when-trying-to-insert-into-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have double quotation marks inside another pair of double quotation marks(" "). In order to do that, you have to diferentiate between the parent quotation marks and the child ones. This can be achieved by using single quotation marks like:

```
String sql = "yada 'yada' yada";
```

Try this:

```
String sql = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA='abcd';";
```

Note: This can be done the other way around, with single quotation marks as parent and double as child.