# JdbcTemplate with chained sql queries?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

How can I chain multiple sql statements into one sql?
Because I want to externalize a bunch of sql statements that should be executed with one jdbctemplate call. So I'm trying to chain them into one update statement:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable; CREATE TABLE mytable like source_table;");
```

Result:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE mytable like source_table;' at line 1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515471/can-i-execute-multiple-queries-separated-by-semicolon-with-mysql-connector-j

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565481/how-to-do-multiple-inserts-in-database-using-spring-jdbc-template-batch