# Why does my code produce the error: The statement did not return a result set

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

I am executing the following query from Microsoft SQL Server Studio, which works fine and displays results:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO   #temp_table
FROM   md_criteria_join
WHERE  user_name = 'tecgaw'

UPDATE #temp_table
SET    user_name = 'tec'
WHERE  user_name != 'tec'

SELECT *
FROM   md_criteria_join
WHERE  user_name = 'tec'
   AND view_name NOT IN (SELECT view_name
                         FROM   md_criteria_join
                         WHERE  user_name = 'tecgaw')
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   #temp_table
ORDER  BY view_name,
      user_name,
      crit_usage_seq,
      crit_join_seq
```

However, if I execute the same query in Java, an Exception is thrown stating

> The statement did not return a result set.

Here's the Java code:

```java
statement = conn.getConnection().createStatement();
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql.toString());
```

Is that because I cannot do multiple SQL queries in one statement (I.e., Creating the `#temp_table`, updating it, and then using for it my select statement)?

Comment: You CAN rewrite this as a single query.  I can help you with this if you indicate which columns comprise the primary key on `md_criteria_join`.

Comment: The pk are the four last columns i am using to do the order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found similar question in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804730/2312621). You should enable connection to support multiple statements and separate them using `;`. For concrete examples see that answer. However it is for MySql only.

Also I think you can rewrite your SQL into single query

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, 'tec' as user_name from md_criteria_join
WHERE (
       user_name = 'tec' 
   AND view_name NOT IN (
       SELECT view_name 
       FROM md_criteria_join 
       WHERE user_name = 'tecgaw')
   )
   OR user_name = 'tecgaw' 
ORDER BY view_name, user_name, crit_usage_seq, crit_join_seq
```

Another option is to move your statements to stored procedure and ivoke it from JDBC using CallableStatement

Or maybe you should try executing it with multiple jdbc statements like this

```
Connection conn = conn.getConnection(); //just to make sure its on single connection
conn.createStatement("SELECT INTO #temp_table").executeUpdate();
conn.createStatement("UPDATE #temp_table").executeUpdate();
conn.createStatement("SELECT ...").executeQuery();
```

Note you have to close resources and maybe for better performance you could use addBatch and executeBatch methods

Comment: The answer you link to is MySQL specific. JDBC statements should execute one statement at a time, not multiple statements.

Comment: No your query is not the same as mine

Comment: indeed it misses the point that you are chaing user_name from tecgaw to tec. One alternative is to use stored procedure and invoke it via jdbc

Comment: I have updated query. If you have not too much columns you can list them and hardcode user_name value.

Answer (score 46):

JDBC is getting confused by row counts.

You need to use `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: In the case of MS sql, this is the first solution that you should try. @John thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Use `execute` statement for **data manipulation** like **insert, update and delete** and 
`executeQuery` for **data retrieval** like **select**

I suggest you to separate your program into two statements one `execute` and one `executeQuery`.

If you do not wish to do that, try separating the statements with semi-colon. But I am not sure about this action if this gives you a resultset or not.

Comment: Ok, if i create separate statements. when will the temp_table vanishes ? After i close the results set, the statement or the connexion ?

Comment: Temp table will be vanished soon after the execution of first executeexecute statement. In that condition. Use a stored procedure and `CallableStatement`

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli You are awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in ms sql you also have to do set nocount on right at the beginning of the stored procedure along with terminating select / update/ insert block statement with ";"

Comment: Oh my God thank you so much! I had a similar issue and the 'SET NOCOUNT ON' statement solved it.