# How do I escape the colon (:) in a mysql query over jdbc that contains a variable assignment?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, query-variables

I'm trying to run a query that involves a custom variable over JDBC toward a MySQL 5.0 database (Hibernate 4 as the ORM):

```
SET @rownum := 0; SELECT rnum FROM (
    SELECT (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rnum, col_name_a
    FROM table_name
    WHERE (col_name_b IS NULL  OR col_name_b != 'USER' )  ORDER BY col_name_a) c
WHERE col_name_a = :aValue
```

The first `SET @rownum := 0;` is needed to reset the variable, but the colon isn't required there (I've set the *allowMutilQuery=true* as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement)).

The problem is with the following `SELECT`, where I keep on getting:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'

Is there a way around this? Should I use other methods than

```
javax.persistence.Query q = EntityManager instance>.createNativequery(String)
```

and

```
q.setParameter(<param name>, <param value>)
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In hibernate the escape of the colon `:` is done with a backslash:

```
SET @rownum \:= 0; SELECT rnum FROM ( ...
```

Or in java:

```
String sql = "SET @rownum \\:= 0; SELECT rnum FROM ( ...";
```

Comment: Great! Do you know if that will be ORM-independent?

Comment: I do not know of any standard in JPA query language, jpql. The definition of parameters, colon+identifier, would not need escaping the colon. But know, I have never encountered this problem.

Comment: @Joop Eggen will it also work in case of a stored procedure, `lp_dyn:LOOP` I have this in a dynamic stored procedure I have to write, but it gives me an error when I escape it with '//'

Comment: @endlessProgrammer `"....lp_dyn:\\:LOOP..."` isn't it (backslash, twice when inside quoted string? I do not know.

Comment: @Joop Eggen Yeah! My bad, I meant `\\\`. but this doesn't work inside of a stored proc.

Comment: @Joop Eggen did you just use double colon ?? was that intentional ?

Comment: side Note: Escape of backslash(as in file path) is also done with another backslash.