# Inserting data into Multiple tables

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
String insert1 = "INSERT INTO  Table1(Col1, col2, col3)"
    + "VALUES(?,?,?)";

String insert2 = "INSERT INTO  Table2(Colx, coly)"
    + "VALUES(?,?)";

Connection conn = aConn;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {   
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert1);
 // ps.addBatch(insert2);
```

I'm trying to Insert Data into multiple tables at a time, and it seems like `addBatch(String sql)` is not defined for PreparedStatement.
Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Maybe check this out if it applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a `PreparedStatement` is used to cache a single SQL statement. This has the advantage that the driver/database might optimize the statement since it is expecting many of them and since it is a parameterized statement. If you want to use it for two different SQL statements you need two `PreparedStatement`s.

In order to add rows to the statement you need to set your parameters using `set*(1,...)`, `set*(2,...)`, `set*(3,...)`, etc. and then call `addBatch()` (no arguments!). Finally you submit the batch of statements using `executeBatch()`.