# Syntax error in Java code, but running in MySQL workbanch

Tags: java, mysql

My query running perfect in workbanch but not working with Java sending exception that MySQL syntax error:

```
Set @total=0;
SET @amountDue=0;
SELECT (l.paid_date),c.customer_name,IF(@total=0,(SELECT total_amount FROM 
payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99)-(SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM
payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99)*(SELECT (total_installments) 
FROM payment_loan
   WHERE loan_id=99),
       (SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM payment_loan WHERE
       loan_id=99))AS AmountDue,
           @amountDue:=@amountDue+(SELECT IF(@total=0,(SELECT (total_amount)
          FROM payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99)-(SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM payment_loan 
        WHERE loan_id=99)*(SELECT (total_installments) FROM payment_loan 
        WHERE loan_id=99),(SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM 
      payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99))) as ComulativeDue,
     l.amount AS AmountPaid, @total := @total +l.amount AS comulativePaid, 
     (@total/@amountDue ) as percentage FROM payments_details l Join 
     customer c on (c.customer_id=l.customer_id) WHERE l.customer_id=115 
    GROUP BY l.paid_date ORDER BY   l.paid_date DESC LIMIT 1  ;
```

and my java code is:

```
     PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.Connect.con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            cName = rs.getString(2);
            amountDue = rs.getInt(3);
       }
```

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET
>   @amountDue=0; SELECT (l.paid_date),c.customer_name,IF(@total=0,(SELECT
>   total' at line 2

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @amountDue=0;
SELECT (l.paid_date),c.customer_name,IF(@total=0,(SELECT total' at line 2

Comment: Please add that into the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

modify your query so:

```
SELECT (l.paid_date),c.customer_name,IF(@total=0,(SELECT total_amount FROM 
payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99)-(SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM
payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99)*(SELECT (total_installments) 
FROM payment_loan, (SELECT @total:=0, @amountDue:=0) setup
   WHERE loan_id=99),
       (SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM payment_loan WHERE
       loan_id=99))AS AmountDue,
           @amountDue:=@amountDue+(SELECT IF(@total=0,(SELECT (total_amount)
          FROM payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99)-(SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM payment_loan 
        WHERE loan_id=99)*(SELECT (total_installments) FROM payment_loan 
        WHERE loan_id=99),(SELECT (installment_amount_month) FROM 
      payment_loan WHERE loan_id=99))) as ComulativeDue,
     l.amount AS AmountPaid, @total := @total +l.amount AS comulativePaid, 
     (@total/@amountDue ) as percentage FROM payments_details l Join 
     customer c on (c.customer_id=l.customer_id) WHERE l.customer_id=115 
    GROUP BY l.paid_date ORDER BY   l.paid_date DESC LIMIT 1  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, multiple queries in a single call are not allowed. This is described very well in [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement):

> While sending a connection request, you need to append a connection
>   property `allowMultiQueries=true` to the database url. This is
>   additional connection property to those if already exists some, like
>   `autoReConnect=true`, etc.. Acceptable values for `allowMultiQueries`
>   property are `true`, `false`, `yes`, and `no`. Any other value is
>   rejected at runtime with an `SQLException`.
>
> ```
> String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
> ```
>
> ...