# how to write two insert query for two different table in one connection in java?

Tags: java

```
            String sql="insert into tablelOne(c_date,order_no,table_no,ord_menu,quantity,customer_name,captain_name,table_status) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";`
            PreparedStatement pstmt=DbModel.preparedStatement(con, sql);
            pstmt.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) sqlDate);
            pstmt.setLong(2,Order_no);
            pstmt.setLong(3,table_no);
            pstmt.setString(4,Order_Menu_Name);
            pstmt.setLong(5,item_Quantity);
            pstmt.setString(6,customer_name);
            pstmt.setString(7,Captain_name);
            pstmt.setLong(8,table_book_status);
```

After that I use same value to insert into another tableTwo  where to write that query.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: how to write two insert query for two different table in one conncection in java?

Comment: same way as you did for first one without creating connection obj again.

Comment: use the same connection, you write another query below.

Comment: Ok satya sir I will try it and let you konw.Thanks

Comment: this will help you :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement