# Total row-count for MySQL multi-queries

Tags: java, mysql, rowcount

I realized today that the row-count returned for data manipulations done via multi-queries is not what I expected it to be:  Executing

```
"INSERT INTO test SET bla=1; INSERT INTO test SET bla=2;"
```

on an empty table `test` returns the row-count `1` and not the total count of rows changed by this statement (which is `2`).  (I know that I could combine these specific `INSERT` statements;  this is just an example of a multi-query which returns a counterintuitive row-count.  I am *not* looking for `INSERT INTO test (bla) VALUES (1),(2)`.)

Is there any way to receive the total row-count when executing multi-queries in Java?

Comment: Why the hate (-1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you will need to iterate through the return for more results:

See

[Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement/10804730#10804730)