# setAllowMultiQueries in MySQL Connector/J 6.0.4

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector, multi-query

In MySQL Connector/J 5.1.39 there was `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.setAllowMultiQueries()` to allow multiple statements in SQL queries.

In new version 6.0.4 MysqlDataSource is moved to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` and there is no `setAllowMultiQueries` method.

How can I enable execution of multi-statement queries?

**UPDATE**

This question is not duplicate of [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10797794/746347).

I know that I can specify `allowMultiQueries` in JDBC url by calling `MysqlDataSource.setUrl()` but I use various `MysqlDataSource.set*` methods to set server, port, etc. In previous version there was same method for allowing multi-queries. I want to understand why it's gone.

Comment: The [6.x Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) still lists `allowMultiQueries` as a valid parameter for the connection URL, so it should be in there *somewhere*....

Comment: The answer is in the connection string. The answer to why it is gone is in someone's head in a development team and Primary Opinion based. Your question was: *How can I enable execution of multi-statement queries?*  ... and to that there is a duplicate question (several) and answers on them