# JDBC & Microsoft SQL Server / How to set AllowMultipleQueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

How to set AllowMultipleQueries on JDBC for Microsoft SQL Server?

My connection string is currently following, but it not works.

```
private final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:11435;databaseName=myDatabase;allowMultiQueries=true";
```

Comment: why not use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: I need execute: INSERT INTO ......; SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [id];

Comment: Use `getGeneratedKeys()` with your `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I tryed it, but not works :-( The result was 1, not latest id.

Comment: I tryed this, but It not works: int insertedId = stmt.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

Comment: `allowMultiQueries` is specific to MySQL. Don't expect **non-standard** features of one database system/driver to be exactly the same (or even available at all) for another.

Answer (score 3):

With Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server you don't need to add anything special to your connection URL in order to enable multiple statements in a single `execute`. This works fine:

```java
connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;databaseName=myDb";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, myUserID, myPassword)) {
    System.out.printf("Driver version %s%n", conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());

    try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
        st.execute("CREATE TABLE #test (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, textcol NVARCHAR(50))");
    }

    String[] itemsToInsert = new String[] { "foo", "bar" };

    String sql = 
            "SET NOCOUNT ON;" +
            "INSERT INTO #test (textcol) VALUES (?);" +
            "SELECT @@IDENTITY;";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        for (String item : itemsToInsert) {
            ps.setString(1, item);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                rs.next();
                int newId = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.printf("'%s' inserted with id=%d%n", item, newId);
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

producing

```
Driver version 6.0.7728.100
'foo' inserted with id=1
'bar' inserted with id=2
```

However, in this particular case it would be better to use JDBC's built-in support for retrieving generated keys:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO #test (textcol) VALUES (?)";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    for (String item : itemsToInsert) {
        ps.setString(1, item);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            rs.next();
            int newId = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.printf("'%s' inserted with id=%d%n", item, newId);
        }
    }
}
```

producing the exact same results.

Comment: thanks for the detailed example and comments, this should be accepted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

why not use a stored procedure instead? Instead of setting `allowMultiQueries` you should rather use a stored procedure like below

```
create procedure usp_data
as
begin
INSERT INTO ......; 
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [id];
end
```

Now call that stored procedure from your code behind. You can as well parameterize the procedure if needed. See this existing post [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement/28142845)

Comment: I dont like this solution, because Im using @@IDENTITY often, and for each use, I need to create new procedure :-/ Does exist another good solution for get the latest id?

Comment: @steelbull, NO, you don't need to create new procedure but need to call the proc instead of multi adhoc queries

Comment: THX @Rahul. Multiple queries are definitely not supported on JDBC for MSSQL?