# After deleting a row I want the primary key to start from 1 again.So is it possible

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Below is a sample of what I did

```
 {   
  ...

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionStr,"root","root");

    String prepareStr="DELETE FROM customer_maintenance where id=?";
    PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(prepareStr);
    pst.setInt(1,id);
    pst.executeUpdate();
   String update_key="SET @count = 0; UPDATE customer_maintenance SET customer_maintenance.id = @count:= @count + 1;";  

PreparedStatement   pst1=con.prepareStatement(update_key);
    pst1.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("UPDATE");


 }
```

It is throwing the following exception

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax

and I am not sure if it is possible to update the primary key, every time a row is deleted.

Comment: What is the exception you get ?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: if u have this field set to AutoIncrement, don't miss with it, just leave it. when you create relations (if u will) later, this could make them invalid, when primaryKey-forignKey wise. jsut leave it as is, u will get used to it :)

Comment: Can you help me with this problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the exception you get, but the first problem I see in your code is that you may try to update a row setting `ID = x`, while another row could still have `ID = x`, thus an error for duplicate key.

That's because that update statement won't guarantee that the rows are updated following the ID order.

With the values in your example:

```
Start  Delete    Update1   Update2
ID     ID        ID        ID
1        (del)
2      2         2         2
3      3         1 (upd)   1
4      4         4         2 (upd)  <- duplicate key
```

**Edit**

Easiest fix is adding an `order by` clause to your query, so that the rows are update starting from the smaller `ID`.

You should also get rid of the `;` at the end of the query.

```
String update_key="SET @count = 0;
    UPDATE customer_maintenance
    SET customer_maintenance.id = @count:= @count + 1
    ORDER BY customer_maintenance.id";
```

Comment: Yes sir i got what you said and that was really helpful..But can u help me or  give me some hint to solve the problem

Comment: And when i use this query "SET @count = 0; UPDATE ........."  directly in mysql it works fine

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution

Comment: Thank you sir...i ll try this

Comment: Have you configured your database connection to allow multiple queries? If not, read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Comment: Glad it helped! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set auto increment and primary key for Id column while table creation. Auto increment will handle this automatically while database deletion, no need to worry about it.

Comment: what i want is,suppose there are 4 pk [1,2,3,4] and i d delete pk[1] than i want the new pk as [1,2,3,4] but what i am getting is [2,3,4]