# query works on mysql but not in java

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
statement2=Myconn.prepareStatement("SET @rank:=0; update entretien "+
                    " set numero_entretien=@rank:=@rank+1 where vehicule_id=?;");
statement2.setInt(1,1);
statement2.executeUpdate();
```

This query works on mysql workbench , but it doesn't work in java

I have latest MySQL and JDBC version ,I think that the problem is maybe in the ";" that follow @rank:=0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. By default it is not possible to execute more than one query per statement. But you can enable multiple query support by appending `?allowMultiQueries=true` to the jdbc connection string.

You can find more details in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement/10804730#10804730).