# How to inject a SQL command to drop a table in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

My java code for SQL Query is

```
String sqlSt="INSERT INTO users(id,name,place) values ("+null+",'"+request.getParameter("name")+"','"+request.getParameter("place")+"');";
```

I have tried out 
    `name= a'); DROP TABLE users; --`
as well as
`place =a'); DROP TABLE users; --`

but it returns an Ecxeption as below

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE users; --','chennai')' at line 1

Note: when i tried the same in mysql command line. It worked!!!! i don't know what happens in jdbc

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Comment: Note that the issue with the + in the query can also come from some quote in the name "L'albatros" for example

Comment: why don't you try name = a and place = a'); drop table users; --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is actually JDBC, it only allows one sql if you dont tell it otherwise.
Look at this question for more info:

[Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement)

But also i would try this instead, name =

```
a',''); DROP TABLE users; --
```

Since you specificed 3 columns in your insert:

```
(id,name,place)
```

You need to provide 3 values for the sql to be valid, not just 2.

Also you can sent the text null, sending a java null value is not necessary and i am not even sure how that works. I think this might be better:

```
String sqlSt="INSERT INTO users(id,name,place) values (null,'"+request.getParameter("name")+"','"+request.getParameter("place")+"');";
```

Comment: WoW!! Thanks ..... just added the attribute to allow multiple query in the URL it self..... worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of null, use an empty string `''`

```
String sqlSt = "INSERT INTO users(id, name, place) values ('', '" + request.getParameter("name") + "',  '" + request.getParameter("place") + "');";
```

It's better to use prepared statements to avoid confusion.

```
String sqlSt = "INSERT INTO users(id, name, place) values ('', ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("name"));
    ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("place"));
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    ps.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is with your Query. It is better to use a `PreparedStatement` for executing a query.
Your Code should be :

```
String sqlSt="INSERT INTO users(id,name,place) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try{
pstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlSt);
pstmt.setString(1,null);
pstmt.setString(2,request.getParameter("name"));
pstmt.setString(3,request.getParameter("place"));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    pstmt.close();
}
```

If you don't want to use a `PreparedStatement`, just remove last `;` from your query.
So your query will be :

```
String sqlSt="INSERT INTO users(id,name,place) values ("+null+",'"+request.getParameter("name")+"','"+request.getParameter("place")+"')";
```