# Hibernate cannot execute native query SqlExceptionHelper : Invalid value "7" for parameter "parameterIndex"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I have native SQL request and it consist of two

- insert - select (with subrequest)
- select

The parameter is list of three String elements and passed to:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = " "
//close
+ "INSERT INTO status (is_open,advertisement, updated) "
+ "SELECT "
+ " false, to_close.id, NOW() "
+ "FROM( "
+ " SELECT " 
+ "             ad.id as id, " 
+ "             ad.native_id as native_id, " 
+ "             sc_newest.updated as updated, " 
+ "             status.is_open as is_open " 
+ " FROM advertisement AS ad " 
+ " LEFT JOIN " 
+ "         (SELECT "
+ "             MAX(sc.UPDATED) AS updated, "
+ "             sc.ADVERTISEMENT "
+ "         FROM ADVERTISEMENT AS ad "
+ "         LEFT JOIN STATUS AS sc "
+ "             ON  ad.ID = sc.ADVERTISEMENT "
+ "         WHERE   ad.NATIVE_ID NOT IN  :shown_ads "
+ "         GROUP BY sc.advertisement) AS sc_newest "
+ "     ON ad.id = sc_newest.advertisement "
+ " LEFT JOIN status AS status "
+ "     ON ad.id = status.advertisement AND status.updated = sc_newest.updated "
+ " WHERE "
+ "     status.is_open = true " 
+ "     AND ad.native_id NOT IN :shown_ads) AS to_close ; "
+ ""
// get stored previously 
+ " SELECT "
+ " ADVERTISEMENT.NATIVE_ID "
+ "FROM ADVERTISEMENT "
+ " WHERE "
+ " ADVERTISEMENT.NATIVE_ID IN :shown_ads "
        , nativeQuery = true)
public Set<String> closeReopenFindStored(@Param("shown_ads") List<String> shownNaturalIDs);
```

Here the log

> 2017-08-03 07:44:12.353 DEBUG 16162 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.SQL                        :
>
> INSERT INTO status (is_open,advertisement, updated) SELECT    false,
>   to_close.id, NOW() FROM(  SELECT              ad.id as id,                ad.native_id as
>   native_id,                sc_newest.updated as updated,               status.is_open as
>   is_open   FROM advertisement AS ad    LEFT JOIN           (SELECT
>                 MAX(sc.UPDATED) AS updated,                 sc.ADVERTISEMENT            FROM ADVERTISEMENT AS ad            LEFT JOIN STATUS AS sc              ON  ad.ID =
>   sc.ADVERTISEMENT          WHERE   ad.NATIVE_ID NOT IN  (?, ?, ?)          GROUP BY
>   sc.advertisement) AS sc_newest        ON ad.id = sc_newest.advertisement
>     LEFT JOIN status AS status      ON ad.id = status.advertisement AND
>   status.updated = sc_newest.updated    WHERE       status.is_open = true
>         AND ad.native_id NOT IN (?, ?, ?)) AS to_close ;   SELECT
>     ADVERTISEMENT.NATIVE_ID FROM ADVERTISEMENT  WHERE
>     ADVERTISEMENT.NATIVE_ID IN (?, ?, ?)
>
> 2017-08-03 07:44:12.429 TRACE 16162 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
>   [VARCHAR] - [ad1 number] 2017-08-03 07:44:12.430 TRACE 16162 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4]
>   as [VARCHAR] - [ad1 number] 2017-08-03 07:44:12.431 TRACE 16162 --- [ 
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7]
>   as [VARCHAR] - [ad1 number]
>
> 2017-08-03 07:44:12.432  WARN 16162 --- [           main]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90008, SQLState:
>   90008 2017-08-03 07:44:12.433 ERROR 16162 --- [           main]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid value "7" for
>   parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-195]

**Why this not works?**

**Update - SQL I run from SQL client fine:**

```
INSERT INTO status (is_open,advertisement, updated) 
SELECT 
    false, to_close.id, NOW() 
FROM( 
    SELECT 
                ad.id as id, 
                ad.native_id as native_id, 
                sc_newest.updated as updated, 
                status.is_open as is_open 
    FROM advertisement AS ad 
    LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                MAX(sc.UPDATED) AS updated, 
                sc.ADVERTISEMENT 
            FROM ADVERTISEMENT AS ad 
            LEFT JOIN STATUS AS sc 
                ON  ad.ID = sc.ADVERTISEMENT 
            WHERE   ad.NATIVE_ID NOT IN  ('ad1 number','ad2 number', 'new ad') 
            GROUP BY sc.advertisement) AS sc_newest 
        ON ad.id = sc_newest.advertisement 
    LEFT JOIN status AS status 
        ON ad.id = status.advertisement AND status.updated = sc_newest.updated 
    WHERE 
        status.is_open = true 
        AND ad.native_id NOT IN ('ad1 number','ad2 number', 'new ad')) AS to_close ; 


SELECT 
    ADVERTISEMENT.ID AS ad_id,
    ADVERTISEMENT.NATIVE_ID
FROM ADVERTISEMENT
WHERE
    ADVERTISEMENT.NATIVE_ID IN ('ad1 number','ad2 number', 'new ad')
```

Comment: Confused - how can it have two parts? an `insert` followed by a separate `select` ?

Comment: or do you mean not have have the semicolon at `AS to_close ; "`

Comment: Can you please share your git hub repository link.

Comment: Well, as Hibernate can execute SQL queries, I think it should be able to do same what I doing in SQL client. I not found any limitations about this in docs yet. In SQL client I can run few SQL commands and separate them with ";" sign.

Comment: I think you are passing value in String at the place of integer

Comment: Share your query with values that is used in SQL client

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/Pavlo_M/database.git

Comment: native_id is varchar. The Advertisement.nativeId is a String property generated by oter system. I just store it. You can see this in test class closeReopenFindStoredTest method

Comment: OK see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804730/2310289 `String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true"; `

Comment: I updated with SQL command I tested before move this to Java code

Comment: @Scary Wombat the link you gived about mySQL while I use H2 database. In H2 multiple queries should work by default http://h2-database.66688.n3.nabble.com/dose-h2database-support-multiple-queries-td4031455.html You can try to clone my repository (it contains just couple of tests) so you will see any details there.

Comment: Pavlo, the link that you gave gives the same remedy as both my comment and the links I gave you - **that is the connection url needs** `allowMultiQueries=true`  - can not see where in you link it says it works by default

Comment: You right I messed with links. Though when I tried to update connection like spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;allowMultiQueries=true I got an error states about dialect not set. But with dialect set to MySQLDialect and mode  MODE=MySQL it not works either.

Comment: maybe *org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect* see http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html

Comment: This not works too.

Comment: I have figured out your problem and post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your code and I have figured out your problem. The problem is that you can not run 2 queries i.e. `insert and select` query at using the same method because your insert query and select query return type are not same so you have to create 2 different methods 1st for saving data and 2nd for selecting data from the database. You have to modify  your code like below

**AdvertisementRepository.java**

```
//  @Modifying
    @Query(value = " "
    //close
//  + "INSERT INTO status (is_open,advertisement, updated) "
//  + "SELECT "
//  + " false, to_close.id, NOW() "
//  + "FROM( "
//  + " SELECT " 
//  + "             ad.id as id, " 
//  + "             ad.native_id as native_id, " 
//  + "             sc_newest.updated as updated, " 
//  + "             status.is_open as is_open " 
//  + " FROM advertisement AS ad " 
//  + " LEFT JOIN " 
//  + "         (SELECT "
//  + "             MAX(sc.UPDATED) AS updated, "
//  + "             sc.ADVERTISEMENT "
//  + "         FROM ADVERTISEMENT AS ad "
//  + "         LEFT JOIN STATUS AS sc "
//  + "             ON  ad.ID = sc.ADVERTISEMENT "
//  + "         WHERE   ad.NATIVE_ID NOT IN  :shown_ads "
//  + "         GROUP BY sc.advertisement) AS sc_newest "
//  + "     ON ad.id = sc_newest.advertisement "
//  + " LEFT JOIN status AS status "
//  + "     ON ad.id = status.advertisement AND status.updated = sc_newest.updated "
//  + " WHERE "
//  + "     status.is_open = true " 
//  + "     AND ad.native_id NOT IN :shown_ads) AS to_close ; "
//  + ""
    //reopen
//  + "INSERT INTO status (is_open,advertisement, updated) "
//  + "SELECT "
//  + " true, to_reopen.id, NOW() "
//  + "FROM( "
//  + " SELECT " 
//  + "             ad.id as id, " 
//  + " FROM advertisement AS ad " 
//  + " LEFT JOIN " 
//  + "             (SELECT "
//  + "                 MAX(sc.updated) AS updated, " 
//  + "                 sc.advertisement " 
//  + "             FROM status AS sc "
//  + "             GROUP BY sc.advertisement) AS sc_newest "
//  + "     ON ad.id = sc_newest.advertisement "
//  + " LEFT JOIN status AS status "
//  + "     ON ad.id = status.advertisement AND status.updated = sc_newest.updated "
//  + " WHERE "
//  + "     status.is_open = false " //reopen closed 
//  + "     AND ad.native_id NOT IN :shown_ads) AS to_reopen ; "
//  + ""
    // get stored previously 
    + " SELECT "
    + " advertisement.native_id "
    + "FROM advertisement "
    + " WHERE "
    + " advertisement.native_id IN :shown_ads "
            , nativeQuery = true)

    public List<String> closeReopenFindStored(@Param("shown_ads") List<String> shownNaturalIDs);


    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO status (is_open,advertisement, updated) "
    + "SELECT "
    + " false, to_close.id, NOW() "
    + "FROM( "
    + " SELECT " 
    + "             ad.id as id, " 
    + "             ad.native_id as native_id, " 
    + "             sc_newest.updated as updated, " 
    + "             status.is_open as is_open " 
    + " FROM advertisement AS ad " 
    + " LEFT JOIN " 
    + "         (SELECT "
    + "             MAX(sc.UPDATED) AS updated, "
    + "             sc.ADVERTISEMENT "
    + "         FROM ADVERTISEMENT AS ad "
    + "         LEFT JOIN STATUS AS sc "
    + "             ON  ad.ID = sc.ADVERTISEMENT "
    + "         WHERE   ad.NATIVE_ID NOT IN  :shown_ads "
    + "         GROUP BY sc.advertisement) AS sc_newest "
    + "     ON ad.id = sc_newest.advertisement "
    + " LEFT JOIN status AS status "
    + "     ON ad.id = status.advertisement AND status.updated = sc_newest.updated "
    + " WHERE "
    + "     status.is_open = true " 
    + "     AND ad.native_id NOT IN :shown_ads) AS to_close ; "
    + "", nativeQuery = true)
    public void saveCloseReopenFindStored(@Param("shown_ads") List<String> shownNaturalIDs);
```

**AdvertisementRepositoryTestService.java**

```
@Transactional
    public List<String> closeReopenFindStored(List<String> shownAdNumbers){
        advertisementRepository.saveCloseReopenFindStored(shownAdNumbers);
        return advertisementRepository.closeReopenFindStored(shownAdNumbers);
    }
```

**AdvertisementRepositoryTest.java**

```
List<String>  storedPreviously =     
                    advertisementRepositoryTestService.closeReopenFindStored(shownAdNaturalIds);
            assertEquals(2, storedPreviously.size());
```

No change in `AdvertisementRepositoryTest.java`

**Note:** I have changed your return type `Set<String>` to `List<String>` you can change it according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check this now!

Comment: I tried to use separate methods for each SQL statement. This works fine. Thank you.