# Run multiple postgres queries with parameters in java

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm using java with postresql driver and I want to run multiply queries in one statement (if possible)

I'm aware of running batch queries like this:

```
pstmt = connection.createStatement();
pstmt.addBatch("query1 here");
pstmt.addBatch("query2 here");
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

but is there a way to execute multiply queries **with parameters**?

Something like this:

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
           "UPDATE TABLE Example SET name=? WHERE id = ?;\n" +
           "UPDATE TABLE Other SET name=? WHERE id = ?;"
        );
pstmt.setInt(1, "name");
pstmt.setInt(2, id1);
pstmt.setInt(3, "kuku");
pstmt.setInt(4, id2);
pstmt.execute();
```

--

**UPDATE**

The link in the comment ([this](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)) answers half of my question.

In addition, I want to know if there is a way to run two **different** queries.

Lets say the queries above were:

```
  UPDATE table1 SET col=? WHERE id=?;
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

As it seems there is not way to do that... :/
Thanks.

Comment: Using a `PreparedStatement` demonstrated [here](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't found this link at the question you mention.
Still this is about one type of query (that will be run with different parameters in each time), can I do this with two types of queries? (I updated the question with explanation)

Comment: You could try, but I have the feeling that the answer is no

Comment: I found this question: [multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement) seems to have the answer :) Thanks

Comment: Just got to remember, that answer is for MySQL