# Java SQL Injection - MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sql-injection

I am attempting to SQL inject one of my applications for a write up that I need to do for a project.

I have used the following statement:

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO activity (activity_name, user_id, category_id, started, completed) VALUES ('" + activityForm.getName() + "', '" + user.getId() + "', '" + category.getId() + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "')";
System.out.println(insertTableSQL);
statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
```

When I then put the following into one of my form inputs (in this case the activity name input):

> ActivityName'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --

I get the following error:

```
INSERT INTO activity (activity_name, patient_id, category_id, started, completed) VALUES ('ActivityName'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --', '1', '1', '0', '0')
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --', '1', '1', '0', '0')' at line 1
```

I cannot seem to find a way to avoid this error so I hope someone has some ideas.

I am guessing the error is occuring because of the way Statement in java works and the rest of the query being parsed.

Thanks

**EDIT: I know that I should use prepared statements, I do. My application uses ORM with JPA. 
For university, I am just testing how SQL injection works.**

Comment: I want to SQL inject it. That is the point. I am just testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the MySQL JDBC driver does not allow one execute to run multiple SQL statements. This means the type of SQL injection test you show cannot execute. This is a good thing!

You'd have to explicitly allow multi-query when you connect to your JDBC data source, by putting `allowMultiQueries=true` in the JDBC URL.

See also [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement)

There are other types of SQL injections that don't run additional statements.

Prepared statements still don't support multi-query, even if you set `allowMultiQueries=true`.

Comment: Ah I did not know that. Brilliant, Thanks!