# mysql statements in java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

So when i use this simple update in mysql using java it gives me the error output that i have a MYSQL syntax fault. but when i copy paste it in mysql gui it works as it supposed to be am i doing something wrong?

```
private static final String UPDATE_PUNTEN_UITDAGING_MAKKELIJK = "UPDATE ID222177_g38.Speler "
        + "set puntenUitdagingenMakkelijk = puntenUitdagingenMakkelijk +3 "
        + " where gebruikersnaam = ? ; "
        + "UPDATE ID222177_g38.Speler "
        + "set puntenUitdagingenMakkelijk = puntenUitdagingenMakkelijk -1 "
        + " where gebruikersnaam = ? ;";


public void uptdatePuntenUitdagingen(String[] uitdaging) {


        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL);
                PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_PUNTEN_UITDAGING_MAKKELIJK)) {
            query.setString(1, uitdaging[0]);
            query.setString(2, uitdaging[1]);

            query.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }}
```

Comment: And the error is? Post complete exception details.

Comment: Not sure if you can execute multiple update queries in the same statement...

Comment: I don't think you can execute multiple commands in a single `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Your query contains multiple statements. See this question on how to enable this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Comment: @lexicore it's a db for a class assignment so i wasn't allowed to do more than one statement at the time so  i splid them up but thanks for the help