# If I execute my query through phpMyAdmin it works while it doesn't in my java program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm new to java and for an exam, I have to make an app that's a store for a book shop but I'm having problems with the database part of the app: my prepared statement isn't working while if I copy the query generated from it and paste it into phpMyAdmin it works perfectly.

The error the app is giving me is:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @address =
>   LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO utenti (email, password, nome, cogn' at
>   line 1

The method that generates the error

```java
public static void createUser(String email, String password, String nome, String cognome, long telefono, String indirizzo, int cap, String città) throws Exception{
        Connection conn = MysqlConnection.getConnection();

        try{
            st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO indirizzi (indirizzo, cap, città) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?); "
                    + "SET @address = LAST_INSERT_ID(); "
                    + "INSERT INTO utenti (email, password, nome, cognome, telefono, idindirizzo) "
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @address);");
            st.setString(1, indirizzo);
            st.setInt(2, cap);
            st.setString(3, città);
            st.setString(4, email);
            st.setString(5, password);
            st.setString(6, nome);
            st.setString(7, cognome);
            st.setLong(8, telefono);

            System.out.println(st);

            st.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
        finally{
            try{
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

The method where it's used (just a test method to see if the other one works)

```java
    private static void createUser()
    {
        try {
            ModelUser.createUser("a@a.com", "qwertyasdfg", "Aldo", "Simone", 391234567890l, "via dietro 1/g", 37051, "Sì");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The generated sql

```sql
INSERT INTO indirizzi (indirizzo, cap, città) VALUES ('via dietro 1/g',37051,'Sì'); SET @address = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO utenti (email, password, nome, cognome, telefono, idindirizzo) VALUES ('a@a.com', 'qwertyasdfg', 'Aldo', 'Simone', 391234567890, @address);
```

A little edited for readability

```sql
INSERT INTO indirizzi (indirizzo, cap, città)
VALUES ('via dietro 1/g',37051,'Sì');
SET @address = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO utenti (email, password, nome, cognome, telefono, idindirizzo)
VALUES ('a@a.com', 'qwertyasdfg', 'Aldo', 'Simone', 391234567890, @address);
```

I think that this should be working since the query itself is working when it's put into phpMyAdmin

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement ... if you want to use multiple queries you need to configure your jdbc driver correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent all morning searching for an answer and couldn't find it. It worked right away!

Comment: However you should consider using only one query per statement as that is generally more readable. (I think instead of using @address you should be able to call LAST_INSERT_ID() directly in the 2nd query).

Comment: I thought the LAST_INSERT_ID() would output the last id of "utenti" instead. I'll try that also! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually trying to execute two queries with one prepared statement. change your method like following

```
public static void createUser(String email, String password,
          String nome, String cognome, long telefono, String indirizzo,
          int cap, String città) throws Exception{

    Connection conn = MysqlConnection.getConnection();

    try{
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO indirizzi
                (indirizzo, cap, città) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        st.setString(1, indirizzo);
        st.setInt(2, cap);
        st.setString(3, città);
        st.executeUpdate();

        /* You may want to close PreparedStatement here */

        st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO utenti
              (email, password, nome, cognome, telefono, idindirizzo)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, LAST_INSERT_ID())");        
        st.setString(1, email);
        st.setString(2, password);
        st.setString(3, nome);
        st.setString(4, cognome);
        st.setLong(5, telefono);
        st.executeUpdate();
         /* You may want to close PreparedStatement here */
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }finally{
        try{
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```