# What's the fastest way to run a lot of SELECT queries in JDBC with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I've done a lot surfing and have found contradictory/unclear answers. Suppose I have 100 SELECT queries that I'd like to run. None of the queries in any way depend on the others. The returned is relatively small (each ResultSet is only a few rows), so bandwidth isn't an issue. My DB is remote, so my biggest source of latency stems from round-trip-time.

Is there any way I can do this in a single RTT? What's the fastest way I can get all the results back?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804730/15741634

Answer (score 0):

After some testing of all the alternatives I've come across, the fastest way to accomplish this (by far) is to create a stored procedure.