# What is the PostgreSQL equivalent of `allowMultiQueries=true`?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I want to execute multiple select statements in the same JDBC query, in order to amortize network latency over a number of related queries, as described in this question:

> [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement)

The accepted answer is to use `allowMultiQueries=true`. Unfortunately, this is a feature specific to the MySQL JDBC driver.

What is the equivalent in PostgreSQL JDBC?

Comment: The example in the linked question could be done in a single query in Postgres. If you have non-trivial statements, I doubt that sending all of them in one go makes a measurable difference to be honest. Make sure you are using a connection pool in your application to avoid opening a new physical connection for each query.

Comment: Additionally: you don't need such a parameter in Postgres. You can just run `"select a,b,c from one_table; select x,y from other_table;"` using `Statement.execute()`.  Then you can use `Statement.getMoreResults()` and `Statement.getResultSet()` to iterate over all ResultSets