# jaydebeapi only exceptions from the first statement in Cursor.execute

Tags: python, sql-server, jaydebeapi

I'm connecting to a SQL Server from Python using `jaydebeapi`. When executing multiple `;`-separated SQL-Statements in a **single** `Cursor.execute`-call only errors from the *first* statement are thrown. Meaning that: when running

```py
curs.execute("""
corrent/successfull insert statement;
insert statement violating a foreign key;
""")
```

no Error is thrown. How do I make `jaydebeapi` or the SQL-Server stop on error?

One option is to use multiple `jaydebeapi.Cursor.execute`-calls, i.e.

```py
curs.execute("corrent/successfull insert statement")
curs.execute("insert statement violating a foreign key;")
```

This is tricky in my situtation, as I need to execute a complete SQL-file which includes newlines and semicolons within quotes. Wrapping inside a transaction (with `SET XACT_ABORT ON`) does not work: while the transaction is of course not executed, no Python error is thrown, nor was I able to access any error message on the `jaydebeapi.Cursor`.

Comment: Our of interest, why use `jaydebeapi` (which by the look of it's repo hasn't been updated in ~3 years) and not something like PyODBC?

Comment: Are you sure the additional statements are being executed? The JDBC driver may be configured to accept only single statements. See `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794`.

Comment: sometimes it helps to append: `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning to handle badly written jdbc libs (ie. all jdbc libs). Also, for sql server, you need to traverse eventual result sets to get a hold of some errors, so you should do that

Comment: I believe `jaydebeapi` was chosen, as the SQL-Server **J**DBC-Driver is already installed in our execution environment (Azure Databricks). Having the internet access blocked makes installing the **O**DBC-Driver quite anoying. The additonal SQL-Statements are definitely being executed.

Comment: Using `SET NOCOUNT ON` causes the error to be thrown. Combining with `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, the further execution is stopped (altough this flag on its own supresses the error). Using `jaydebeapi ` I was not able to access any result sets (only running `insert`s without `output`); tried all `Cursor`-methods. Switching to `pyodbc` gives access to `Cursor.nextset()` which will throw.

Comment: Great, as to why, NOCOUNT OFF makes sql server driver / or Server itself i don't remember, generate fake resultsets with counts. Since some errors comes in later code, one need to get those results first before SQL Server will send TDS error tokens. Some drivers don't expose the NOCOUNT OFF resultsets, since they aren't really resultsets, make these errors harder to get. Oh well, don't forget to raise a cold one for SET NOCOUNT ON;